# How can I use urllib to parse a url but input multiple url's into a text prompt?

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib

I'm using urllib to parse a url, but I was wanting it to take input from a text box so I could put in multiple url's whenever I needed instead of changing the code to parse just one url. I tried using tkinter but I couldn't figure out how to get urllib to grab the input from that.

Comment: Maybe show what you've tried.

Comment: I cannot show what I've tried due to it being me constantly trying to change the code back and forth. I've used 
def retrieve_input():
    input = self.myText_Box.get("1.0",END) for tkinter and tried to get urllib parse to get the input but I don't know entirely how.

Comment: maybe first use `input()` to get url. You can also run script with arguments in console and get it as `sys.argv`. Or use moduel `argparse` to run script with arguments.

Comment: `tkinter` has simple dialogs to ask for values - https://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much information on your use case but let's pretend you have multiple URLs already and that part is working.

```
def retrieve_input(list_of_urls): 
    for url in list_of_urls:
        # do parsing as needed
```

Now if you wanted to have a way to get more than one URL and put them in a list, maybe you would do something like:

```
list_of_urls = []
while True:
    url = input('What is your URL?')
    if url != 'Stop':
        list_of_urls.append(url)
    else:
        break
```

With that example you would probably want to control inputs more but just to give you an idea.  If you are expecting to get help with the tkinter portion, you'll need to provide more information and examples of what you have tried, your expected input (and method), and expected output.

Comment: No this is fine, I just used input and added this along with parsing and it works. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Voted but I have low rep so it wont show publicly :(